# glMultiDrawElements stops my code

Tags: cocoa, opengl

I'm trying to learn OpenGL with "the redbook", and I'm now at the point were I'm testing glMultiDrawElements. I already got my code to work with glDrawElements, and other "simpler" methods, but it stops working here, and now I'm completly stuck. My code is supposed to draw a cube, and the acctuall drawing code is posted under:

```
GLfloat verticies[] = {-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5};
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, verticies);
GLubyte front[] = {4, 5, 6, 7};
GLubyte left[] = {0, 3, 7, 4};
GLubyte right[] = {5, 1, 2, 6};
GLubyte back[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
GLubyte bottom[] = {0, 1, 5, 4};
GLubyte topp[] = {2, 3, 7, 6};
GLvoid *faces[6] = {front, left, right, back, bottom, topp};
glMultiDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, faces, 6);
glFlush();
```

The program is cocoa based, and compile fine, but stops under running due to "EXC_BAD_ACCESS". There is a yellow warning triangle next to glMultiDrawElements(..) saying "incompatible integer to pointer conversion", but i tought i was using pointers in the "faces" array (at least that exactly how it looks in "the red book"). Can somone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to `glMultiDrawElements()` is a pointer to an array of sizes, not a numerical value for a size. This is why the compiler is complaining about an integer to pointer conversion (which, by the way, is another reason why you should enable the compiler flag for turning warnings into errors when doing Cocoa development).

I believe changing the above to read

```
GLsizei count[] = {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4};
glMultiDrawElements(GL_QUADS, count, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, faces, 6);
```

should work, but I haven't tested it here.